# jQuery Templating vs. PHP echoing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, jquery-templates

I'm writing a search engine and I'm trying to figure out the best way to display the results (5 per page).

I'm newer to dynamic web development, so bear with me. Currently, the processing is done server side in PHP, and the results are echoed into proper format using a large block of HTML code. While this works just fine, it's not the easiest to maintain if I decide to change the HTML, and quite frankly, it looks messy. Like this, but more involved in the HTML:

```
while($rows)       
   echo "<div class='someClass'>".$rows['name']."[...]</div>"
```

Other than cleaning things up, what, if any, are the gains from switching to a jQuery template that uses data from an AJAX call? Would it be best to keep things in PHP to hide all processing from the user (and not expose any calls to .php files)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use php `<<<EOF` ([heredoc](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)):

```
<?php

    $test = "something";

    $str = <<<EOF
    <p>Hello</p>
    <p>$test</p>
EOF;
    echo $str;
?>
```

This will allow you to have a large block of easily readable HTML in the PHP. I wouldn't use AJAX calls with JQuery.

Comment: @Peter Thanks, forgot what it was called :)

Answer (score 0):

Security wise it doesn't make too much of a difference if you expose your ajax calls. Performance wise it's all about whether or not the client (end user) renders the template which would be the case using jQuery or the server renders the template. This means that initially the user won't see any of your actual content until after the page is fully loaded and your jQuery is given the chance to fire off an ajax request and receive the response. Whereas doing it with PHP renders with the page and is displayed technically before the page loads.

That said I personally have used both options.

Comment: Okay, sounds good. I didn't know if, performance-wise, I was making things more sluggish than they ought to be. I'll probably use the EOF method that webnoob suggested.

Comment: @Jon Be careful when using that as you still may end up with large portions of unmaintainable code. If you're new to templating I suggest looking into Smarty PHP. It's a PHP based templating system that lets you abstract your templates into actual template files instead of leaving them scattered through your code.

Comment: Well it's generally frowned upon to mix your model (the PHP code) with your template (the HTML), if you mix them too much and start doing things like escaping ?> for specific strings it makes it harder to find out what the PHP code is really doing, especially in a Class structure where certain functions have HUGE HTML snippets. If you want a really good example of something you learn to avoid go pull down a copy of wordpress and look through some of their template code.

Comment: Thanks Peter. This is great to know.